# problems with entity translation insert hook

Tags: 7, hooks, entities, i18n-l10n

I'm using the **entity_translation_insert()** hook to set the value of a field when a node is translated.
I can successfully edit the $entity from within the implementation, but how should I save the resulting node?

I can't call node_save because it would start an endless loop. I tried field_attach_update but the result is the same (i.e. loop).

I've tried following this article, with no luck: http://anthonypower.com/notebook/assigning-node-field-values-hook-insert-and-update-right-way

Answer (score 0):

A trick to bypass this could be to use a static variable to process nodes only once per request, e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_translation_insert().
 */
function yourmodule_entity_translation_insert($entity_type, $entity, $translation, $values = array()) {
  static $processed = array();
  if ($entity_type == 'node' && !isset($processed[$entity->nid])) {
    // Do something
    $processed[$entity->nid] = TRUE;
  }
}
```